# how to get custom route for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I use codeigniter and i am working on my maintenance controller but would like to know what the best way is to request it to go to my maintenance route. And not sure if laid controller out correct for it.

My Routes
    // Catalog End Users

```
$route['maintenance'] = "catalog/common/maintenance";// Need to request this route.

$route['account/login'] = "catalog/account/login";
$route['account/register'] = "catalog/account/register";
```

Maintenance Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Maintenance extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
if ($this->config->set_item('config_maintenance')) {
$route = '';

if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
$part = explode('/', $this->request->get['route']);

if (isset($part[0])) {
$route .= $part[0];
}           
}

// Show site if logged in as admin
$this->load->model('model_setting');
}
}
}
```

Just because I would like to have the controller in my catalog/frontend but be able to turn it on and off in my admin when login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom Controller

If you create a custom controller, 
you can check if the website is in maintenance in the __constructor.
Anything thing then that inherits from it, will have the rule apply.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Check to see if the user is anything other than
        // admin, and redirect them.
        // Do your own authoring here.

        if(config_item('maintenance_mode') && $currentuser->group != "admin"){
            return $this->load->view('maintenance');
        }
    }
}
```